# Spark MapWithState to manage session state

Tags: database, apache-spark, spark-streaming, stateful

I am working on a use case where I need to continuously collect and process information for on-going user sessions on their smart phones. Smart phone application contacts server and keeps sending session related parameters to the server throughout the session. Application typically reports session metrics every 15-20 seconds. A typical session lasts 15-20 minutes but may go upto 1-2 hours as well. The session metrics have to be available on a dashboard which not only pulls metrics for on-going sessions but historical sessions as well (last 30 days) 
 
 I am using Spark Streaming with MapWithState functionality to manage session state. I keep pushing updated state info to an external database after every spark batch. Currently dashboard only queries external database. 
I am worried about the performance of such a system since the database upserts become far too many when the system is under heavy load. The latest session info has to be available on the dashboard (strict business requirement).
What can be the refinements which I can work on? Spark has a concept of JDBC server. Can I make use of that somehow? If yes, I will have to juggle between database (for historical sessions) and Spark (for on-going/recent sessions). 

 FYI: I can't afford to use Spark Structured streaming as state management is quite complex in my case.

Comment: *I am worried about the performance of such a system since the database upserts become far too many when the system is under heavy load*. Lets assume you've defined "heavy load" under some concerete number. Once you hit that number, would it be OK as by business rules to delay inserts to the database? Because it really all depends on that, IMO. If you can't have any such delay, then you need to look for a database which can give you the proper SLA performance you require.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: I cannot delay inserts into database since the data won't be available on dashboard immediately. I have tried multiple database technologies already but I believe upsert rate is the key. Is there an alternative like Spark JDBC server?

Comment: Since you seem open to trying multiple database technologies you should give [SnappyData](https://www.snappydata.io) a try. SnappyData deeply integrates Spark with an in-memory database such that they run on the same JVM. This eliminates crossing kernel boundaries when upserting to the DB and improves performance. Disclaimer: I work for SnappyData.